# transfer session from one jsp page to another using javasccript

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, session

In my Spring java application, I am trying to transfer a retrieved java session from one page to another using javascript and this is the attempt in the first jsp page

```
    <script>

//$(document).ready(

function getNotify() {

    <% String mp = (String) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("sound"); %>
        var mp = "<%= mp %>";
        console.log("value>>>>>>> "+mp);//returns the actual value

    <%  request.getSession().setAttribute("sound7", mp);  %>


}

setInterval(getNotify, 2000);

</script>
```

In the second jsp, I am trying to retrieve the session like this but it returns null

```
<% String postSound = (String) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("sound7"); %>
    var postSound = "<%= postSound %>";
    console.log("value of postSound>>>>>>> "+ postSound );
```

Please how can I transfer session from jsp A to jsp B using the above approach.

Comment: check this https ://github.com/ielatif/stackoverflow/tree/master/SpringMvcExample.
I was misundertanding your issue. I thought that attribute "sound" is setted correctely in the session and the issue was in jsp pages. But no your jsp's are correct the issue is in controller side

Comment: Plz share your controller code.

Comment: I will delete my old answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about `@SessionAttributes` in your controller?
Check this https://github.com/ielatif/stackoverflow/tree/master/SpringMvcExample